# Tried to Load Angular More Than Once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I have a yeoman scaffolded app (the angular fullstack generator).

`grunt serve` works fine, but `grunt build` produces a distribution that locks up memory, most probably because of circular references in angular.

I upgraded angular to `1.2.15`.  The error I get is:

`WARNING: Tried to Load Angular More Than Once`

Prior to upgrading, the error was:

`Error: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

It's pretty difficult to debug as it only happens after build / minification.  All my modules are in angular's array format, so the minification DI shouldn't be a problem but it is.

There's no single script that causes this.  The only way it goes away is if I don't initialize with my app.js file.  My app.js file is below.

Any thing come to mind?

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngTagsInput',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'google-maps',
  'firebase'
]);

angular.module('myApp').config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/listing.html',
        controller: 'ListingCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]).constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'something');
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

This could be a number of issues: essentially it's a problem of routeProvider not finding a file and recursively loading the default.

For me, it turned out that it wasn't minification but concatenation of the js that caused the problems.

```
angular.module('myApp').config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/listing.html',
        controller: 'ListingCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]).constant('FIREBASE_URL', 'something');
```

You'll notice that if the app can't find a file (i.e., `otherwise`), then it will redirect to the root, which in this case loads the `templateUrl`.  But if your `templateUrl` is wrong, then it will cause a recursion that reloads `index.html` loading angular (and everything else) over and over.

In my case, grunt-concat caused the templateUrl to be wrong after build, but not before.

Comment: did this problem occur in 1.2.14 as well?

Answer (score 19):

The problem could occur when $templateCacheProvider is trying to resolve a template in the templateCache or through your project directory that **does not exist**

Example:

```
templateUrl: 'views/wrongPathToTemplate'
```

Should be:

```
templateUrl: 'views/home.html'
```

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful for someone, I got this error when some templates were deleted after merge:
` <div ng-include="'path_to_not_existing_template'"></div>`

Comment: @ryaz yes it was indeed the cause for the problem.

Answer (score 15):

This doesn't have anything to do with `app.js` at all.  Instead, this warning is logged when you include the Angular JS library more than once.

I've managed to reproduce the error in [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jatihaki/1/edit).  Note the two script tags (two different versions):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Relevant Angular code at [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/748a6c8d9d8d61c3ee18eec462abe8ff245d6a98/src/angular.suffix).

Comment: Yea that makes sense, but it actually did have to do with app.js in my case -- I just posted my findings.

Comment: You are a legend! This was in my project from day 1. It is finally solved and now I can sleep in peace. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 14):

Seems like nobody has mentioned this anywhere so here is what triggered it for me:
I had the ng-view directive on my body. Changing it like so

```
<body layout="column">
<div ng-view></div>
...
</body>
```

stopped the error.

Comment: yes, for me having the view be where the `<script>` tags for angular were were causing the issue (my script references are under `<body>`)

Comment: you are the saviour

Answer (score 7):

I was also facing such an issue where I was continously getting an infinite loop and the page was reloading itself infinitely. After a bit of debugging I found out that the error was being caused because, angular was **not able to load template** given with a particular id because the template was not present in that file.

Be careful with the url's which you give in angular apps. If its not correct, angular can just keep on looking for it eventually, leading to infinite loop!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Made my day.. This is undebuggable. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, The problem was the conflict between JQuery and Angular. Angular couldn't set the full JQuery library for itself. As JQLite is enough in most cases, I included Angular first in my web page and then I loaded Jquery. The error was gone then.

Comment: I encountered this issue as well. Moved angularjs script on top for it to load first then put jquery after. Error is now gone.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was getting this error while using jquery as well as angular js on the page.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I removed :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the warning disappeared.

Comment: If this warning appears, this is a sign that you may be trying to load the page recursively. If you remove JQuery the warning may fade, but the problem may still occur, which is actually worse.

Comment: doing this hid the error for me too, but I later discovered that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28727077/2518317) was the real issue

Answer (score 5):

Had this problem today and figured I would post how I fixed it. In my case I had an index.html page with:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainController"
   <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

and in my app.js file I had the following code:

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    controller : 'mainController',
    templateUrl : 'index.html',
    title : 'Home'
  }).when('/other', {
    controller : 'otherController',
    templateUrl : 'views/other.html',
    title : 'other'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
  });
```

As a result, when I went to the page (base_url/) it loaded index.html, and inside the ng-view it loaded index.html again, and inside that view it loaded index.html again.. and so on - creating an infinite recursive load of index.html (each time loading angular libraries).

To resolve all I had to do was remove index.html from the routProvider - as follows:

```
$routeProvider.when('/other', {
    controller : 'otherController',
    templateUrl : 'views/other.html',
    title : 'other'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/'
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, and for me the issue was due to some missing semicolons in the controller. The minification of the app was probably causing the code to execute incorrectly (most likely the resulting code was causing state mutations, which causes the view to render, and then the controller executes the code again, and so on recursively).

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem on code pen, and it turn out it's just because I was loading JQuery before Angular. Don't know if that can apply for other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Capitalization matters as well! Inside my directive, I tried specifying:

```
templateUrl: 'Views/mytemplate'
```

and got the "more than once" warning. The warning disappeared when I changed it to:

```
templateUrl: 'views/mytemplate'
```

Correct me, but I think this happened because page that I placed the directive on was under "views" and not "Views" in the route config function.

Comment: I had a similar issue: got this error message when the path to my template broke. Thanks :)

Comment: Makes sense! When the template URL is invalid, the core index.html would be coming in the response from the server if errors are not handled properly, which would have the JS includes

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too with .NET and MVC 5 and after a while I realized that within the label on Index.cshtml file:

```
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

again included as section scripts happens to you. To solve the problem on the server side what I do is return the partial view. Something like:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this was my case and now it's fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem ("Tried to Load Angular More Than Once") because I had included twice angularJs file (without perceive) in my index.html.

```
<script src="angular.js">
<script src="angular.min.js">
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, because I have `angular` two times in `index.html`:

```
<script src="https://handsontable.github.io/ngHandsontable/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the warning arises only when `html5` mode is true, when my `html5` mode was false, I did not see this warning.

So removing the first `angular.js` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must change angular route '/'! It is a problem because '/' base url request. If you change '/' => '/home' or '/hede' angular will good work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has this issue in the future, for me it was caused by an arrow function instead of a function literal in a `run` block:

```
// bad
module('a').run(() => ...)

// good
module('a').run(function() {...})
```

Comment: I had the same issue with arrow functions when I tried to rewrite my code using ES6. Do you know why arrow functions work everywhere except for module/controller/service declarations?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have index.html which embeds 2 views i.e view1.html and view2.html. I developed these 2 views independent of index.html and then tried to embed using route.
So I had all the script files defined in the 2 view html files which was causing this warning. The warning disappeared after removing the inclusion of angularJS script files from views.

> In short, the script files angularJS, jQuery and angular-route.js
>   should be included only in index.html and not in view html files.

Answer (score 0):

Another case is with `Webpack` which concating angular into the bundle.js, beside the angular that is loaded from index.html `<script>` tag.

this was because we used explicit importing of `angular` in many files:

```
define(['angular', ...], function(angular, ...){
```

so, webpack decided to bundle it too. cleaning all of those into:

```
define([...], function(...){
```

was fixing `Tried to Load Angular More Than Once` for once and all.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was the following line (HAML):

```
%a{"href"=>"#", "ng-click" => "showConfirmDeleteModal()"} Delete
```

Notice that I have a angular `ng-click` and I have an `href` tag which will jump to `#` which is the same page.  I just had to remove the `href` tag and I was good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was, I had taken backup of controller (js) file with some other changes in the same folder and bundling loaded both the controller files (original and backup js). Removing backup from the scripts folder, that was bundled solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when **missing a closing tag** in the html.

[image]

So instead of:

```
<table></table>
```

..my HTML was

```
<table>...<table>
```

Tried to load jQuery after angular as mentioned above. This prevented the error message, but didn't really fix the problem. And jQuery '.find' didn't really work afterwards..

Solution was to fix the missing closing tag.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the exact same error. After some hours, I noticed that there was an extra comma in my .JSON file, on the very last key-value pair.

```
//doesn't work
{
    "key":"value",
    "key":"value",
    "key":"value",
}
```

Then I just took it off (the last ',') and that solved the problem.

```
//works
{
    "key":"value",
    "key":"value",
    "key":"value"
}
```