# WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am trying to view my app after running Grunt Build. I use grunt serve:dist to see all production ready build but in the browser I get an infinite loop saying:

> WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

I have read this occurs because the TemplateURL: may be wrong after concatenation. As in this post:
[Tried to Load Angular More Than Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595878/tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once)

But how do I fix this? Here is my app.js

```
/* global libjsapp:true */


'use strict';

var libjsapp = angular.module('libjsApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute'
]);

libjsapp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: Do you happen to have any commented out script tags in your files ?

Comment: hey @VishalSakaria, would you mind picking the accepted answer?

Answer (score 39):

In my case this was due to the following html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Testapp</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="testApp">

  <main ui-view>

  <script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

  <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, the `<main>` is not closed. This led to my variant of *'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.'* issue.

Comment: I had this same problem with ng-include - thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thank you, you saved me a lot of time looking in the wrong place. I was concatenating a bunch of files together to make 1 HTML page.  One page had malformed HTML in it and caused the problem.

Comment: `ng-bind` and `ng-bind-html` may lead to the same error

Comment: You sir, are a life saver! *bows down with respect*

Comment: I was getting this error as well with `<ng-view />` on a page with an HTML5 doctype and switching to `<ng-view></ng-view>` removed the warnings.

Comment: You should mark this as the solution. Having said that it's not the solution *for me*, but it seems to be for most people.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and what an insidious one. I had to strip down my angular app to almost _nothing_ trying to debug it before I saw your answer.

Comment: I was facing same warning having the ui-view in the body tag. So, removing from it and putting in a <div></div> solved the warning too.

Comment: I got this error when using `<div ng-view />` on html5 doctype, so I had just to close the tag `<div ng-view></div>`.

Answer (score 31):

This problem also is caused by using the current page as the `templateUrl`. This is especially problematic as it results in an infinite loop referencing itself over and over.

If you are getting an infinite loop that crashes your page, it's probably this. If you are getting CORS errors, it's probably due to including a script tag from another domain in your template.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
   templateUrl: 'an/absolute/url/to/the/current/page.html'
});
```

Comment: Oh! this saved my day.. I was actually seeing the console logs.  When the application loaded it loads localhost:9000/app/main/main.html and when go to another route it used to load as localhost:9000/other.html which it doesnt get, and keeps looping.

Comment: your response had me check my url, to realize I had a typo!

Comment: and check if your template exist where it must be, especially if you are using _automated build system_.
If your server is responding with index page for every missing resource, then you'll get infinite angular loading loop.
I strongly recommend to configure server **not to respond with index page for missing templates**!

Comment: My image (`template`) did exist in the same path as I am using to call `templateUrl` so the error still exists... I think it has something to do with this though. any other advice?

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem because my `templateUrl` path was wrong due to my `index.html` being in a different root structure. Try testing the URL path just using `template` instead of `templateUrl`.

Place an image in your `views` folder, and try this.

```
$routeProvider.when('/', {
   template: 'Test Template <img src="views/pic.jpg"/>',
   controller: 'PostsCtrl'
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

You should see "Test Template" and the image show up on your index page. If the image doesn't show up, your path is wrong.

Comment: Ah, I ran into this same error again, but this time, as it turns out after long struggle, it is due to a typo in the templateUrl path. More interestingly, for the same typo, you get this error if `replace: false`. Otherwise, if `replace:true`, you'll get the error like this: `Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'xxChart' must have exactly one root element. /app/directive/xxChart.html`. Silly.

Comment: I had failed to add a route to my routes.conf file that mapped requests for ng-table templates to path="/public/ng-table" and since it did not find the route it was sending index.scala.html back for each template requested. All I did was add the line `GET   /ng-table/*file          controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/ng-table", file)` and it fixed it

Answer (score 7):

I came across the same issue. But in my case, with webpack build two different Angular versions got packaged (Angular 1.5.5 and Angular 1.5.0).

Comment: I had the same issue with webpack but the versions of angular where the same, one was in my main chunk and the other in my vendor chunk

Answer (score 3):

Yeah I sorted it out by moving the post.html into partials and changing the templateUrl to partials/posts.html. I think this might be due to the Yo scaffold I used which was angular fullstack, because it work fine of the see project. Thanks anyway

Comment: This was basically the same issue I had. The problem was that I misspelled my template name in the templateURL.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in fact related to angular library being loaded too many times.

My reply can sound too obvious, but the code itself is fine and there's not much information on what the problem can be. If you can post your folder tree, maybe it can be useful.

In the meantime, please ensure these two things are ok before investigating further:

- views/posts.html does not include a script tag with the call to angular.js library.
- views/posts.html file is available in that position (maybe use a complete URI).

Answer (score 2):

I confirm all above (usually routing errors or some error on resources paths or ng-app error).

I would like to add only a point to help to find the error (not in case of wrong ng-app).

If we suppose the server for angular is setted as follow:

- /static/* for all static resources (js, css, png...)
- /api/* rest api
- /* all others call will be redirect to index.html

In this way all wrong path will return index.html instead of png, css, js and tpl files, even if is missing /static/ path or miss to return 404 for missing  static resources.

in short: **check the log on server witch paths are you calling opening the page**, the error evidence could be found there.

Answer (score 2):

You must change angular route '/'! It is a problem because '/' base url request. If you change '/' => '/home' or '/hede' angular will good work.
Sample:

Module.Js:

```
var application = angular.module('flow', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);
```

RouteConfig.Js:

```
angular.module('flow')
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', { templateUrl: '/home/index', controller: 'HomeController' })
            .when('/error', { templateUrl: '/Error/Index', controller: 'ErrorController' })
            .when('/login', { templateUrl: '/Account/Login', controller: 'AccountController' });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the cause of the warning was a redundant script inclusion of "angular-scenario.js" after "angular.js".

When I removed "angular-scenario.js" warning disappeared.

Comment: This was my problem as well, it only happened after I updated to AngularJS 1.5.8

Answer (score 1):

I recently got this error and the way I solved it was to go into the Web.config and change `<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>`
to `<compilation debug="true" ... />`
I hope this helps someone! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution might work locally for example if your running grunt serve, but when you run a grunt build  your view might not be included in the dist directory. For example if you have a view and that view is in views>templates>***modules*** anything more than ***two levels*** wont be added when you run grunt build by default. At least that was the case for me. Check if your html file is being included into the dist directory in views. If its not add your files manually to verify that it works, then update your grunt file acordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was related to AngularJS Batarang Chrome Extension (version 0.7.1). Once I disabled the extension the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, angular library and my angular module code is dynamically loaded inside another application which I dont have any control. And these are loaded on click of of a button. For the first time its working fine but when user clicks 2nd time the library and other files loads again and it gives me the warning.

WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

```
var isInitialized = element.injector();
if (!isInitialized) {
  angular.bootstrap(angular.element(document.getElementById('#mainDiv')), ['defaultApp']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This case is when the code takes to infinite loop somehow. Make sure you verify if there are any redirections in your code which are called multiple time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the template file (not string) was empty. when I filled the template file with simple html, the problem has been solved. Fill `views/posts.html` with some code.

Answer (score 0):

We were accidentally trying to load a non-existent route in a `ui-view`.  The route, however, did correspond to a valid URL that contained an Angular app.  It instead loaded that Angular app into the `ui-view`, hence the multiple copies of Angular.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `app-view-segment="1"` was missing and there was two references pointing to the same folder of angular in the index.cshtml file, in the `@Scripts.Render` lines. 
Thanks for pointing to the angular routing.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one more possible scenario to this issue...

**Behavior**: everything works fine when loaded from the root URL, but you run into this issue whenever loading your page from any other route (or entering another route).

**Likely reason**: one of your nested components or pages is loading something from a *relative* path instead of an *absolute* path.

In my case it had to do with a referenced component loading its template with a relative path.

So, for example changing from this:

```
angular.
  module('app').
  component('profileSelect', {
    // this line was the problem
    templateUrl: 'static/angular/profiles/profile-select.html',
    bindings: {}
  });
```

to this:

```
angular.
  module('app').
  component('profileSelect', {
    // making this an absolute path fixes it
    templateUrl: '/static/angular/profiles/profile-select.html',
    bindings: {}
  });
```

Resolved it. Basically because you now have sub-paths those relative references no longer work, and angular decides to fail in this incredibly hard-to-decipher way.

Hopefully someone is helped by this answer. I just lost an hour+ of my life to it...

Answer (score 0):

Last time this happened to me, it was a leading '/' in a route's templateUrl, which wasn't suppose to be there.

This time though, it was a bunch of views not getting rendered into the template cache after build because I've placed those views in a sub folder of a sub folder under the views folder. Gruntfile.js wasn't tuned to pick up 3rd level folders from '/views'.

To find out what was rendered in a yo-grunt build, you can look at .tmp/templateCache.js after the build finishes.

I do wish AngularJS LTS's team will find a way to better handle this kind of error, with some better clue as to where the problem is.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and found that the problem occurred in my karma.conf.js file.

When specifying which file patterns to load into the browser, I used a wild card identifier to load AngularJS like so:

```
'path_to_angular/angular/*.js
```

If there's more than one file loading AngularJS within that directory, like angular.js and angular.min.js for example, then this error will be thrown.

To avoid this error, simply specify a single path with no wildcards.

```
'path_to_angular/angular/angular.js'
```

or

```
'path_to_angular/angular/angular.min.js'
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The issue/fix we had might be a little unique because we're using webpack + AngularJS.

We are using `html-webpack-plugin`. However, our `index.html` file also had

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./bundle.js"></script>
```

The `html-webpack-plugin` automatically adds that line, so it was in our resultant HTML twice.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem and that's why I'm landed here. However, none of the answers worked for me. It turns out that nothing is wrong in code, and the browser url is the culprit: it should be `localhost:3000/#/`, but somehow, I got something like `localhost:3000/xxx/public/index.html/#/` in my browser. By the way, I'm using ui-router with node.js in WebStorm if it matters.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was an invalid resource link in index.html

```
<link rel="import" href="/somethingmissing.html">
```