# AngularJS + Rails: Back Button "WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I can go my app and change pages without an issue. Using the back button is also not a problem...unless I return to the point in the history where I first opened the application. So, index -> pg 1 -> index -> pg 2 allows me to press the back button twice, returning me to the index and then pg 1. The next back click yields this error and the ng-view does not load:

```
"WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once."
```

It's clear that usually the back button is just using the $routeProvider which looks like this for me (more routes than shown, but the structure is the same)

```
  .config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('sampleUrl', {
          templateUrl: 'sampleTemplate',
          controller: 'sampleCtrl'
        }).
        otherwise({
          redirectTo: 'sampleUrl'
        });
    }]);
```

However the last back button no longer is merely using just the $routeProvider to update the ng-view but also reloading the Rails layout that holds the ng-view. The general structure of the layout is as follows

```
%html{ 'ng-app' => 'myApp' }
  %body#dashboard(ng-controller='baseCtrl')
     navbar stuff
     %section.clearfix.aaux(ng-view)
javascript include tag for rails asset pipeline
```

My Rails root looks like this

```
  root "dashboard/patients#index"
```

Here's what I've looked at/contemplated so far:

[Tried to Load Angular More Than Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595878/tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once)

Irrelevant. My templateUrl is correct for all routes; unless I click back to the beginning all is fine and dandy.

This

> "But if your templateUrl is wrong, then it will cause a recursion that
>   reloads index.html loading angular (and everything else) over and
>   over."

might be relevant, as it is reloading the page with ng-app on it which I believe is also what index.html is in their app. But from what I've seen of Rails apps integrating with Angular it's common practice to put the

```
%html{ 'ng-app' => 'ekoApp' }
```

on the layout.

[WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once. Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499853/warning-tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once-angular-js)

I definitely only have one ng-app in my application, but it IS being loaded twice. Regardless, without an extra ng-app to delete, this solution wasn't particularly helpful.

My most recent thought is that there might be something funky with having a root to an empty html page and using my layout to render the ng-view rather than a Rails view.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Took everything in the body into the index.html and then within the layout just did

```
= yield
```

The situation remains exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing turbolinks solved the problem. I had assumed it was fine since this was the only weird error I was getting, but guess not. I'm confused as to why it was causing this problem however, so any explanation that covers that thoroughly I'll mark as the right answer.