# Having some trouble understanding middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

So I want to set up a basic node server to work with my clientside Angular application. My folder structure looks like this:

```
.tmp //Contains css stylesheet
bower //Obviously contains bower packages
public //Contains client code
```

This is what my `index.html` looks like (at least, the scripts/stylesheets)

```
 <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/.tmp/styles.css">
  <!-- endinject -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->

<!-- inject:js -->
<script src="/public/app/modules/sportStore.module.js"></script>
<script src="/public/app/controllers/checkout.controller.js"></script>
<script src="/public/app/controllers/productList.controller.js"></script>
<script src="/public/app/controllers/sportsStore.controller.js"></script>
<script src="/public/app/filters/customFilters.js"></script>
<script src="/public/app/components/cart/cart.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

And this is my middleware configuration in my server.js file:

```
app.use(logger()); //require('morgan')
app.use(express.static('./'));
app.use(express.static('./public/'));
app.use(express.static('./tmp/'));
app.use('/*', express.static('./public/index.html'));
```

What I understand this does is that: for *every* request:

1. Log it
2. See if you can find the file request under ./
3. If it's not there, looks under ./public/
4. If it's not there, look under ./tmp/
5. If it's not there and the request contains something after the '/' serve index.html

How I'm going to handle client-side routing (with Angular's `$routeProvider`) is not clear to me yet, perhaps I won't even need to do that, I'm not sure if those requests will go to the server.

However doing all of this results in an infinite loop and I honestly have no idea why. I thought I understood middleware but obviously there's something wrong with my logic, or this would be working.

So basically my 2 questions are:

1. Is what I summed up how express' middleware works?
2. If it's not, perhaps you could give me a push in the right direction?

Don't just point me to express' docs, I've read them over like 5 times but I find that the documentation doesn't explain it clearly enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close. Your static routes look OK. The biggest issue with this is the 'path' - not the middleware. I think what you want is:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
   res.redirect('/public/index.html'); // note: redirecting to root, not ./public
});
```

However it may be better to not serve up *everything* statically! You could do the following:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public');
app.use('/bower', express.static(__dirname + '/bower'));
app.use('/.tmp', express.static(__dirname + '/.tmp'));

app.use(function(req, res) {
   res.redirect('/public/index.html');
});
```

That will avoid any issues with files of the same name in different folders etc, and hides the code you don't want to give people access to...

Comment: route != middleware ?

Comment: Btw, that gave me the same endless loop. Just removing it did load the page, however my ng-view directive didn't load the default view then, really odd

Comment: This is in the loaded page: <!-- ngView: undefined -->

Comment: Updated my answer there. The above code works for me locally - let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, only tries one request: the request to '/' fails

Comment: Fails how? Here is a minimially working test application: https://github.com/olanb7/express-test You can play around with the `index.html` locations.

Comment: Fails as in: can not retrieve any page

Comment: I played around a bit with your app, thanks for that. As to what actually fixed my infinite loop, it was a simple self-closing ng-view tag that was the problem, the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499853/warning-tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once-angular-js fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

A short answer is that middleware is everything you can plug for your requests' lifecycle. A good way to see how it works is to code a simple middleware, such as a very very basic logger middleware :

```
var logMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    // We do some logging
    console.log(req.method+" "+req.url);

    // Because this is a **middle**ware, we can stop the request here
    // using the res object, or call next() and it will continue it's 
    // lifecycle.
    next();
}


app.use(logMiddleware);
```

The order in which you register your middlewares (using `app.use`) does matter, it is a chain as you said in your original question.

Edit: Regarding Angular, you can have a look at [this blog post](http://briantford.com/blog/angular-express) and see how the routes are setup server-side. It's a bit old, but this part has not changed in express.

Comment: I'll take a look at that article, thanks for your answer! I'll also try out that piece of code to better understand it