# WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to route in angular.js (1.3.15)and getting these two errors :

**error messages**

> ```
> 1-WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
>
> 2-angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=after_login&
> p1=Err…0d%20(http%3A%2F
> %2Flocalhost%3A49062%2FScripts%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)
> ```

**my module.js**

```
var after_login = angular.module("after_login", ['ngRoute', 'CrackWeb']);


after_login.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/groups',
                    {
                        templateUrl: 'Views/p1.cshtml',
                        controller: 'MyScripts/groups'
                    })
              .otherwise(
                        {
                            redirectTo: '/'
                        });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

in my html page with ng-app i have written.

**p1.cshtml [ partial ]**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <br />
      <input ng-model="check" id="ch"/>
        {{check}}
      <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: how about the controller ?

Comment: after_login.controller('groups', function ($scope) {
    $scope.login = function (userName, pass) {
        alert(userName+pass);
    
        var url = 'http://52.11.190.113/api/account/login';
        $http.post(url, { email:userName, password:pass, deviceregistrationid: '67788' })
            .success(function (data,$location){
               alert("success"+"   "+ data.message);
            });
    }
});

Comment: did you add ng-app="after_login" in your html ??

Comment: here is what i added <body ng-app="after_login">

Answer (score 0):

In your route provider you have mentioned

`$routeProvider.when('/groups',
                    {
                        templateUrl: 'Views/p1.cshtml',
                        controller: 'MyScripts/groups'
                    })
              .otherwise(
                        {
                            redirectTo: '/'
                        });`

but **you dont have default route**

`$routeProvider.when('/',
                    {
                        templateUrl: 'sometemplate',
                        controller: 'somecontroller'
                    });`

so it will try to load your default HTML(most cases index.html) again and again and it cause the error

Comment: i have otherwise(
                        {
                            redirectTo: '/'
                        });

Comment: you have to mention template and controller for `/` otherwise it will try to load your index.html again !!!

Comment: [code]     $routeProvider.when('/',
                            {
                                templateUrl: 'Views/index.html',
                                controller: 'MyScripts/login_controller'
                            })                                     i added this code it is not helping

Comment: do you have angularjs core file in your index.html!!! if possible add your index.html in your question

Comment: there was not before now i have added but not helping at all.

Comment: you should not load angular core file in your index.html!!! there may be some other reasons causing you problem !!!! will you be able to create  a plunker reproducing your issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499853/warning-tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once-angular-js refer this link

Comment: my url is http://localhost:49062/#/groups but it should be likhttp://localhost:49062/Views/#/groups what should i change in route

Answer (score 0):

You can not load a page with cshtml extension!

Actually you are wrong when you try to load the page CSHTML through the ANGULAR ROUTING.
As you can not load this page alone so well you can not load it through ANGULAR route.

So if you want to load a page CSHTML then you have to call his controller in MVC
 and to load it via 'ActionResult'.