# Angular, third part modules and Browserify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browserify

I'm developing a little app which uses Angular and Browserify. When I declare a new module I expect to Angular be already loaded in window, so I use

```
 var angular = window.angular
```

and so on. This work well, but since I'm requiring a third part module (ngReact) declared as

```
 require('ngReact')
```

I get this message on the console:

```
 WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

How can avoid it?

Comment: var angular = window.angular;  var app = angular.module('someApp',['ngReact']);

Comment: I forgot to specify this too. Sorry. I'm already doing this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tried to Load Angular More Than Once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595878/tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once)