# AngularJS bootstrap accordion causing AngularJS to load more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've had this problem for a few days now and I can't get to the bottom of it.
I'm using Gulp to build my project. In the `gulpfile.js` I have the following:

For my `JS`

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src([
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular/angular.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/jquery/jquery.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-ui-select/dist/select.min.js',
        DIRSOURCE + 'lib/angular-tour/dist/angular-tour-tpls.min.js'
    ])
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DIRDEST + 'lib/'));

    gulp.src([DIRSOURCE + 'modules/module.js', DIRSOURCE + 'modules/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DIRDEST + 'modules'));
});
```

For my `CSS`

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src([DIRSOURCE + 'assets/less/sce.less'])
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(rename("style.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(DIRDEST + 'assets/css'));
});
```

All of the above seems to be working fine as the application loads with no errors. The problem arises when I try to add an `accordion` from the `bootstrap ui` library: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I have  the following template file - `sidebar.html`. I want to add the `accordion` here. I have the following markup:

`<div class='col-md-12 other'>
    <uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
    <uib-accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded" is-open="status.isFirstOpen" is-disabled="status.isFirstDisabled">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </uib-accordion-group>
    <uib-accordion-group heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </uib-accordion-group>
    <uib-accordion-group heading="Dynamic Body Content">
      <p>The body of the uib-accordion group grows to fit the contents</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-click="addItem()">Add Item</button>
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</div>
    </uib-accordion-group>
    <uib-accordion-group heading="Delete account" panel-class="panel-danger">
      <p>Please, to delete your account, click the button below</p>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </uib-accordion-group>
    <uib-accordion-group is-open="status.open">
      <uib-accordion-heading>
        I can have markup, too! <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-down': status.open, 'glyphicon-chevron-right': !status.open}"></i>
      </uib-accordion-heading>
      This is just some content to illustrate fancy headings.
    </uib-accordion-group>
  </uib-accordion>
</div>`

The route that assigns the controller to the view is here:

```
 var main = {
        name: "MainPage",
        url: "/",
        title: '`Homepage',
        views: {
            "mainContent": {
                templateUrl: "modules/main/template/home.html",
                controller: "MainPageController"
            },
            "sidebar":{
                templateUrl: "modules/main/template/sidebar.html",
                controller: "SidebarController"
            }
        }
    };`
```

This is the `controller` associated with sidebar.html

```
application.controller('SidebarController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$state', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $translate) {
    console.log('Sidebar controller');
    $scope.oneAtATime = true;
    $scope.groups = [
        {
            title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 1',
            content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 1'
    },
        {
            title: 'Dynamic Group Header - 2',
            content: 'Dynamic Group Body - 2'
    }
  ];

    $scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

    $scope.addItem = function () {
        var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
        $scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
    };

    $scope.status = {
        isFirstOpen: true,
        isFirstDisabled: false
    };


}]);
```

My application is declared along with the libraries required in `application.js` like this:

```
var application = angular.module('sceDemo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ngSanitize', 'pascalprecht.translate', 'ui.select', 'angular-tour']);
```

However when I run

`gulp clean && gulp && gulp server`

and load up my app in browser the area that should show the accordion seems to have loaded the `index.html` file again and when I view my console I see this error message:

```
warning: tried to load angular more than once
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is, all I've established is that it is being caused by trying to add the accordion as when I remove it the problem is resolved. any help is much appreciated.

I hope I've provided enough information. If not please request and I will supply.

Thanks!

Comment: I went into the same problem and finally figured out that it was because i had an ng-view on my body element.

Comment: I just checked my markup and I don't have an `ng-view` on body so I don't know if thats the cause in this instance!

Comment: see this question. may be it's help u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595878/tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once

Comment: Could also be a problem of route not matching and then calling every time the default route with and with it the angular library

Comment: Could it be something to do with having the two templates being loaded within the one route?