# WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once using ionic and angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I 'm using ionic combined angular. But when the console to run the project : '**WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once**'
Detail bower.json file:

```
  {
  "name": "HelloIonic",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "^3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-aria": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-messages": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.15",
    "bootstrap": "*",
    "angular-bootstrap": "*",
    "angular-spinner": "~0.6.1",
    "angular-loading-spinner": "~0.0.3",
    "satellizer": "^0.12.5",
    "angular-local-storage": "^0.2.3",
    "font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
    "animate.css": "~3.2.0",
    "angular-material": "master",
    "angular-flash-alert": "~1.1.1",
    "angular-utils-pagination": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.2.4"
  }
}
```

Detail app.route file:

```
      (function (angular) {
      'use strict';

      angular
        .module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])

        .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
          $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
              cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

            }
            if (window.StatusBar) {
              // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
              StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
          });
        })

        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$authProvider',
          function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {

            // Satellizer configuration that specifies which API
            // route the JWT should be retrieved from
            $authProvider.loginUrl = 'http://103.237.145.123:8098/v1/mobile/user/login';

            $stateProvider

              .state('app', {
                url: '/app',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
                controller: 'AppCtrl'
              })

              .state('app.search', {
                url: '/search',
                views: {
                  'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/search.html'
                  }
                }
              })

              .state('app.browse', {
                url: '/browse',
                views: {
                  'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html'
                  }
                }
              })
              .state('app.playlists', {
                url: '/playlists',
                views: {
                  'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
                    controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
                  }
                }
              })

              .state('app.single', {
                url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
                views: {
                  'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
                    controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
                  }
                }
              });
            // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/search');

          }]);
        } (angular));
```

Comment: your bower contents have nothing to do with your question.

Comment: and have you seen this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595878/tried-to-load-angular-more-than-once

Comment: the problem is with the content like that when I run the project on warning so it

Comment: If 'app' state has a url, it should not be abstract